# How to disable autoformat in LibreOffice 6 Calc?

Tags: libreoffice

I am using LibreOffice Version: `6.1.5.2`

I cannot find a way to remove autoformat from Calc.

I am trying to enter `00:10:00` as a value and it keeps converting it to `12:10:00 AM`. This is a timecode and I need to build a lot of these.

I have looked online but all I found was a [post from 2012](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/2844/how-can-i-turn-off-all-automatic-formatting/) and that is not applicable. I also would really only like to ignore a column and not turn it off completely but for now I will take a full removal of autoformat. I'm sure it has the capability but I cannot find it at all.

I have tried to *Clear Direct Formatting* but then it converts my value to `0.00694444444444444`... This is pretty frustrating so I am hear asking for help.

Thanks

Comment: Why not select an area and set format to text?

Comment: Dude.... thanks... It took me a min to figure out how to do this. Never thought to right-click... Thanks a lot

Comment: I tried on LO 5, and I didn't have to do it though.

Comment: That's probably why I am now having this problem. It's been a while since I needed to do this and I had no issues before. Maybe it's an 6 issue/feature

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select an input area, right-click it and select "Text" format.

That will disable auto formatting.

I added `00:10:00` to LO Calc 5 and it didn't change though.

Probably they added some automation in the 6 version.

Comment: But "I am trying to enter 00:10:00 as a **value**".

Comment: @DKBose I, and presumably Pilot6 as well, took that to mean "I want to enter the literal string '00:10:00' as a value, and not as a formatted string that gets interpreted and converted to a different numerical value, which then may be re-formatted in a way I don't have control over".